# C program Printf function showing unusual behavior for unsigned long long type?

Tags: c, unix, printf, solaris

Please consider the below program and observe the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long val ;
    val =144111444250;
    printf ("%llu\n", val);
    printf ("%u %llu\n",val, val);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
   144111444250

   33 10211385600662044705
```

Using  %llu in first printf gives correct result but using %llu in second printf is giving wrong result.

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about using `%u` with the `long long unsigned` type.

Comment: `%u` pops only a part of `val` from the stack. Afterwards, `%llu` pops `sizeof(unsigned long long)` bytes, which include the rest of the first attempt to print `val`. When replacing `%u` with `%llu` your program should work fine.

Comment: You use an invalid specifier and get an invalid result. Who's surprised?

Comment: @BoPersson: using  %llu in first printf gives correct result but using %llu in second printf is giving wrong result. That's what my question was all about

Comment: @SHAAN - But it is the first format `%u` that is wrong. And like the answer already says -  once something goes wrong, everything else might go wrong too.

Answer (score 6):

This is *undefined behaviour*: `printf` expects an `unsigned int` for `%u` but you provide an `unsigned long long int`, whatever happens after that is up to the whimsy of the compiler.

The format specifiers for `printf` and `scanf` not only indicate how something should be printed/scanned, but also what kind of arguments to expect. If you lie you can't expect the results to be reasonable.